# How to collect such info in magento listing page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need the catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table `value` data only on listing page.

When i am going to listing page and use the `print_r($_productCollection);`

$_productCollection on listing page returns me a array like this.

```
           [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/product
            [_resource:protected] => 
            [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/product_collection
            [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
            [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [entity_id] => 160
                    [entity_type_id] => 4
                    [attribute_set_id] => 4
                    [type_id] => simple
                    [sku] => 104580
                    [has_options] => 0
                    [required_options] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2014-12-01 10:40:25
                    [updated_at] => 2014-12-01 11:51:15
                    [cat_index_position] => 1
                    [price] => 4.4900
                    [tax_class_id] => 4
                    [final_price] => 4.4900
                    [minimal_price] => 4.4900
                    [min_price] => 4.4900
                    [max_price] => 4.4900
                    [tier_price] => 
                    [name] => E Shisha E Liquid eKaiser *Menthol Flavour* 10ml Platinum Bottle Refill for Rechargeable E cigarette and E Shisha
                    [msrp_enabled] => 1
                    [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => 1
                    [thumbnail] => amazon_images/104580.jpg
                    [small_image] => amazon_images/104580.jpg
                    [image_label] => 
                    [small_image_label] => 
                    [thumbnail_label] => 
                    [url_key] => e-shisha-e-liquid-ekaiser-menthol-flavour-10ml-platinum-bottle-refill-for-rechargeable-e-cigarette-and-e-shisha
                    [short_description] => The eKaiser Platinum e Liquid range is made specifically for Cigarette smokers.
```

I need the only [small_image] value, which returns me only the `amazon_images/104580.jpg`

If any One have any idea, how to do it

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And also you can do like this :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
foreach ($product->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
...
}
```

Comment: It seems working but, can we echo it Only one image for each product without foreach loop?

Comment: $images = $product->getMediaGallery('images');
if(!empty($images)){ 
 $image = $images[0]; 
 if(!empty($image)) { 
  $imagepath=explode('/', $image['file']); $imagename = $imagepath[count($imagepath)-1]; echo $imagename;
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this on listing page.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    var_dump($image->getUrl());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback , but it returns us all image with full path.But we need to show only one, only image name.

Comment: Yeah. No problem for that. You can get that image gallery collection form this method getMediaGalleryImages(). And, choose one what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop in listing with getModel will slow down your listing page considerably.

With listing page you should only use flat tables for collection.

So you need to make sure that small image is populated in flat table.

Comment: I am agree with you but, How can we do it?can you Please explain me?

Comment: in your debug your have [small_image] => amazon_images/104580.jpg.As this is $_data object array part you use getdata('smallImage');

Comment: a while loop $_productCollection as product then product->getData('smallImage')  and check by echo.If you look into any listing phtml page you will get some code to refer.